# Trying to read in a wav file using python on a rasberry pi

Tags: python, scipy, wave

I keep getting the same error message but i am also able to use certain wav files without any errors. This is my code:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
fs, data= wavfile.read('/home/pi/chimp.wav').
```

gives error :

> data=numpy.fromstring(fid.read(size), dtype=dtype)
>
> OverflowError: cannot fit int into an index-sized integer

Comment: What error do you get ? Alos, can you upload a working file and a failing file somewhere so we can test.

Comment: The error message reads: data=numpy.fromstring(fid.read(size), dtype=dtype), OverflowError: cannot fit int into an index-sized integer

Comment: maybe your input file is not a proper wav file. that's why I asked you to upload sample file somewhere so we can reproduce.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the wav file was recorded in the command window on the raspberry pi using arecord, If that is any help at all.